# Nginx and wowza on port 80. How to configure

Tags: nginx, wowza

I have dedicated server with 1 IP. Nginx on port 80 used as reverse proxy. Behind nginx several backends (Apache, PHP Fast CGI)
I also have wowza. It works ok by RTMP on port 1935. I want to allow connect to wowza via RTMPT protocol on port 80.

Is it possible to configure nginx to proxy RTMPT requests to wowza server?

Wowza support didnt help
[link1](http://www.wowza.com/forums/showthread.php?18208-nginx-and-rtmp-on-port-80)
[link2](http://www.wowza.com/forums/showthread.php?1252-Reverse-Proxy)

Answer (score 0):

You can either configure Wowza to listen on port 80 ( without nginx, recommended ) or to use the RTMPT protocol which is RTMP on top of HTTP

Base Nginx only proxies HTTP(s) and SMTP
so yes, this should be possible but is probably slower ( higher protocol overhead, CPU footprint )

*Example configuration in nginx*

```
server
{
     listen          80;
     server_name     _;

     location /
     {
           proxy_set_header        Host            $host;
           proxy_buffering         Off;

           proxy_pass              http://127.0.0.1:YOUR_WOWZA_RTMPT_PORT;
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try this config with real server or its just hypothetical?